# SQL select from multiple tagsid in same row

Tags: php, sql

If I want to select all `recipeid`s that include one `tagsid`, for example:

```
tagsid = 1
recipeid = 2|12|1|8
```

If I use this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM recipe where tagsid like '%".$tag_id."%'";
```

it will show `recipeid` `1` in `tagsid` `12, 1`, but it should be only in `tagsid 1`. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Your database needs to be normalized to easily handle this case. The reason you have a problem is that `1` is in the number `12`, and you're using `LIKE`, which is just looking for any substring.  You could try `like '%|".$tag_id."|%'"`, but that has other issues.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and normalise your data schema ^^

Comment: I think you question became unclear after editing. How can one understand what is `recipeid` while you have `tagsid` in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With delimiters, with delimiter after, but nothing before, or with delimiter before, but nothing after

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE tagsid LIKE '%|".$tag_id."|%' OR tagsid LIKE '".$tag_id."|%' OR tagsid LIKE '%|".$tag_id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find for an occurrence of the `tag_id` either between `|` or if the value starts from this `tag_id` with one `|` after. I think you always have `|` after `tag_id`.

```
$query = 
    "SELECT * 
     FROM recipe 
     where tagsid like '%|".$tag_id."|%'" or 
           tagsid like '".$tag_id."|%'";
```

Two cases should be considered:

`%|<tag_id>|%` - not on the first place

`<tag_id>|%` - on the first place

> it will show recipeid 1 in tagsid 12, 1, but it should be only in tagsid 1. Why is this incorrect?

Because `%` symbol works as a wildcard meaning any number of any symbols.You search for `%1%` pattern. All strings with at least one `1` substring match the pattern. `12|` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()` on the `tagsid` column after replacing the pipes with commas.

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM recipe
          WHERE COALESCE(FIND_IN_SET($tag_id, REPLACE(tagsid, '|', ',')), 0) > 0"
```

By the way, you should avoid storing CSV in a column because it is difficult to work with.